# Google Checkout won't take initial subscription payment

Tags: google-checkout, android-pay

I've been playing with Google Subscriptions for a while now and no matter how hard I try, I'm unable to get the initial payment to be charged.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've set the subscription to be Google managed and everything looks fine to me:

[image: Screenshot of email subscription]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you have a look at the newer Google Wallet Subscriptions API. Much simpler to integrate and debug, simpler UX, and wider availability:

https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/subscriptions

https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/jsreference#sub